# Pandas - how to replace specific values in a Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called `product_type` such as:

```py
df1.product_type.unique()

>> ["prod_1", "prod_2", "prod_3"]

df.prod_cost.dtype

>> dtype('O')
```

I am looking for the most efficient way to replace that by numerical values `[1, 2, 3]`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas.Series.factorize) to encode a new column:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abcdbcbccc')})
df

Out[2]:
   a
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  b
5  c
6  b
7  c
8  c
9  c

In [5]:
df['code'] = df['a'].factorize()[0] + 1
df

Out[5]:
   a  code
0  a     1
1  b     2
2  c     3
3  d     4
4  b     2
5  c     3
6  b     2
7  c     3
8  c     3
9  c     3
```

so in your case:

```
df1['product_type'] = df1['product_type'].factorize()[0] + 1
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Cast the column as a `category`, and then get the codes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'product_type': ['prod_1'] * 3 + ['prod_2'] * 3 + ['prod_3'] * 3})
df1['product_type_code'] = df1.product_type.astype('category').cat.codes

>>> df1
  product_type  product_type_code
0       prod_1                  0
1       prod_1                  0
2       prod_1                  0
3       prod_2                  1
4       prod_2                  1
5       prod_2                  1
6       prod_3                  2
7       prod_3                  2
8       prod_3                  2
```